# What's wrong with that if-else structure?

Tags: c

So, I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to do an exercise where i have to create a program that catches the price and the source code of a product, and through the source code the program will show from where the product came from. So here's the list of the source codes:

- 1 = South
- 2 = North
- 3 = East
- 4 = West
- 5~6 = Northeast
- 7~9 = Southeast
- 10~20 = Midwest
- 25~30 = Northeast

If the source code inserted by the user don't match with any of this list, there will be a message saying that the code inserted has no correspondent in the list. So, I did the exercise and there's the final code:

```
int main() {
    float price;
    int code;
    char check1, check2;

    printf("Hello there! Insert the price of your product: ");
    scanf("%f", &price);
    printf("\nAlright, now enter the source code of the product: ");
    scanf("%d", &code);

    switch(code) {
    case 1:
        printf("Your product came from the South");
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Your product came from the North");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Your product came from the East");
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Your product came from the West");
        break;

    default:
        if(code == 5 || code == 6 || (code >= 25 && code <= 30)) {
            printf("Your product came from the Northeast");
        } else {
            if(code >= 7 && code <= 9) {
                printf("Your product came from the Southeast");
            } else {
                if(code >= 10 && code <= 20) {
                    printf("Your product came from the Midwest");
                } else {
                    printf("Sorry, this code doesn't match with any correspondence");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    printf(" and it costs %0.2f\n", price);
}
```

But I also wanted to do an if-else structure before the program checks if there is any correspondence to give the user the opportunity of correcting something that he inserted wrong or something like that. So I did this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float price;
    int code;
    char check1, check2;

    printf("Hello there! Insert the price of your product: ");
    scanf("%f", &price);
    printf("\nAlright, now enter the source code of the product: ");
    scanf("%d", &code);

    printf(
        "So, the price is %0.2f and the code is %d, right? Press c to continue, r "
        "to reset and any other key to quit: \n",
        price, code);
    scanf("%s", &check1);

    if(check1 == 'c') {
        printf("Let's continue then!\n");
    } else {
        if(check1 == 'r') {
            printf("\n");
            main();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    switch(code) {
    case 1:
        printf("Your product came from the South");
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Your product came from the North");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Your product came from the East");
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Your product came from the West");
        break;

    default:
        if(code == 5 || code == 6 || (code >= 25 && code <= 30)) {
            printf("Your product came from the Northeast");
        } else {
            if(code >= 7 && code <= 9) {
                printf("Your product came from the Southeast");
            } else {
                if(code >= 10 && code <= 20) {
                    printf("Your product came from the Midwest");
                } else {
                    printf("Sorry, this code doesn't match with any correspondence");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    printf(" and it costs %0.2f\n", price);
}
```

The problem is: with this code, the output is always "Sorry, this code doesn't match with any correspondence", no matter what are the input values. Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

(Also, sorry 4 the bad English, I'm still learning)

Comment: Something out of context: You should not call `main()` explicitely in your code. It is even illegal in the C++-Standard and for various good reasons!

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &check1);`  1) the variable `check1` is declared as a single character.  However, the input format specifier: `%s` is expecting a pointer to a character array and will always append a NUL byte to the input.  Suggest using: `%c` as that is expecting a single character.  2) When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.    Note: for the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: Could you tell me other way to do something similar instead of calling `main()`? @AnonymousAnonymous

Comment: @KauãJúniodaSilvaLima A common approach would be to wrap all of your code in a `while(true)` loop and to `break` out, or `continue` if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
scanf("%s", &check1);
```

you can not use the string format specifier (`"%s"`) to scan a `char`, switch to

```
scanf("%c", &check1);
```

or better yet

```
scanf(" %c", &check1); // The leading whitespace will consume the previous newline
```